# visual studio intellitrace with w3wp not working

Tags: visual-studio, intellitrace

How can I run `intellitrace` when attaching to the process `w3wp` in IIS rather than running the site through `casini`. When I try to attach a MVC application to `w3wp` I can debug the site without problem. I would like to see the `intellitrace` when using IIS.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options for using IntelliTrace with IIS:

1. If you are **launching** IIS from the debugger, IntelliTrace should be available.
2. You can choose to use the [Standalone IntelliTrace Collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh398365%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you can enable via PowerShell scripts

Unfortunately IntelliTrace does not support attaching to a process. Please let me know if you need more information on either option.

Comment: how do you launch iis from the debugger